# Hitting a non-character key in an MVC3 required field fires validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model, asp.net-mvc-validation

I noticed that on a log in view, when a user enters in their email address, and quickly tabs to the password field, the MVC3 required attribute validation fires. The code I have is quite large, but I have been able to reproduce it with a very simple page. It is similar to what follows:

I have a very basic view with a model attached. The model has 2 properties, both of which have the [Required] attribute. If you focus one, and hit any key that does not input any characters(eg, Shift, Esc, etc.), the required validation fires, and I get my error message saying that the field is required, even though I have not entered anything yet.

Does anyone know how to prevent this early validation from firing?

Comment: Well... it's not MVC, it's jquery validation plugin.

Comment: Yup, I totally meant that, not sure why I said MVC validation.

Answer (score 0):

Concur with gdordon - disable/fix any jquery validation. Also, you can disable this behavior by disabling Unobtrusive Validation (in web.config) - this is typically enabled and uses jquery for client-side validation.

Comment: I still want the client side validation, it was just validating early, and I needed to not validate when hitting random characters

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was I disabled the keyup event for these input fields, using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("input[data-val-required]").keyup(function () {
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This allows for the client side validation to only go off when the user hits the submit button